# ASP.NET session state in sql

Tags: asp.net, database, session

we use sql server to store sessions of asp.net, when I look at the ASPStateTempSessions table in ASPState database, it is empty, I wondered, are the records in this table get deleted once the session is expired? when will the records be deleted there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The InstallSqlState.sql script creates a job called
>   ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions to delete expired sessions from
>   tempdb. Recall that  ASP.NET does not keep session resources alive
>   indefinitely. To support  this feature when a SQL Server is used to
>   maintain state, the SQL Server  Agent must be running so that the
>   expired session deletion job runs as  needed. By default, the job is
>   scheduled to run every minute. It deletes  session state rows with an
>   Expires value less than the current time.  The account under which the
>   SQL Server Agent runs must have the  privilege to execute the
>   DeleteExpiredSessions stored  procedure.

Please refer [this one](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-10041)

Comment: View ***Performance issues*** about `DeleteExpiredSessions` stored procedure: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/optimize-aspstate

Answer (score 0):

It's been renamed to dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions now.

If you don't have SQL Server Agent, just run it from the command line ie.

```
sqlcmd -S MyServerName -d MyStateDbName -E -Q "DeleteExpiredSessions"
```

Also, you might need to do a DBCC shrink if you're deleting lots of data.